# How do I load my footer after my content has faded in with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, callback, fadein

I've got thumbnail images on my site fading in one at a time on load. I'm wondering how I can get the footer to appear after my thumbnails, so it doesn't show immediately and get pushed down as the images fade in.

After some initial research I realised I needed to add some sort of callback to my function, so I placed an alert in but for some reason it doesn't pop-up after the images fade in.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(window).load(function() {
        var images = $('figure');
        var imageCount = images.length;
        var count = 0;

        var fadeImages = function(image, callback) {
            $(image).fadeIn(170, function() {
                // Increase the count.
                count++;
                if (images[count]) {
                    // Pass the callback to the recursively called function.
                    fadeImages(images[count], callback);
                }
            });

            // Make sure that we're only calling the callback once the images have all loaded.
            if (typeof callback === 'function' && count === imageCount) { 
                callback.call(this); // brings the scope to the callback
            }
        };

        fadeImages(images[0], function() {
            alert('Load footer');  // your callback here
        });
    });
 </script>
```

You will see what I mean on my website [here](http://edharrisondesign.com/portfolio-site/).

My main questions are:

1) How do I get the callback function to run after the images have loaded?

2) Could someone point me in the right direction with what to write to get the footer to appear after the images have faded in?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling the callback only after all your images have loaded.

**Edit:** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pdJfe/1/) showing this code in action.

```
var images = $('figure');
var imageCount = images.length;
var count = 0;

var fadeImages = function(image, callback) {
    $(image).fadeIn(170, function() {
        // Increase the count.
        count++;
        if (images[count]) {
            // Pass the callback to the recursively called function.
            fadeImages(images[count], callback);
        }
    });

    // Make sure that we're only calling the callback once the images have all loaded.
    if (typeof callback === 'function' && count === imageCount - 1) { 
        callback.call(this); // brings the scope to the callback
    }
};

fadeImages(images[0], function() {
    alert('Load footer');  // your callback here
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Daniel, but I tried that out and the alert didn't pop-up at all. Do you think it may be because I'm using the Figure element?

Comment: OK - check out this JSFiddle using the code above, you'll see it working and with a fading footer: http://jsfiddle.net/pdJfe/1/ - let me know if you have any problems applying this to your code.

Comment: There was also an error in my original code - `count` will never equal `imageCount` if it starts from zero, but we need it to be zero for the image indices. Therefore, you'll see a bit has changed to compare `count` to `imageCount - 1`.

Comment: Just checked out your JSFiddle and you've nailed it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

you need to bind on callback called onload on all images
for example you have 10 images, with jquery:

```
var imagesLoaded = 0;
    // alter this selector to match only your images you want to wait for
    $("img").load(function() {
       imagesLoaded++;
       if(imagesLoaded == 10) {
          // all 10 images are loaded, show footer
       }
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't you still have the problem, since the `load` function will be called before any animation - in this case, `fadeIn`?

Comment: simply move this logic to the fadeIn callback function